# Are there any individual full stack freelancers on Upwork who have earned $500k+ till now?

Tags: freelance-websites, web-development, marketing, freelance

As well as they earned more than $20K in a single project. I wonder if achieving this level of income requires working as part of a team or if a single freelancer like myself can accomplish it alone.

What skills do I need besides full-stack development to achieve such a milestone?

[Earnings are before tax]

Comment: Lifetime earnings or in one year?

Comment: 500k what? $,¥,Rs? What time period? Before or after tax?  The question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: $500K, it is a lifetime earning and they are still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many people who are independent freelancers with such incomes. However, many of them consider UpWork to be one of many venues for getting work.

The skills needed to be successful can include sales and marketing skills, negotiation skills, as well as financial and accounting skills. One of the key points in my work is to recognize how much time and effort is needed to be put into sales and marketing, to plan for that time and effort, and to manage my schedule so that I put in the effort to do marketing.

Remember that clients do not want a "full stack developer". They want their business problems solved. That their problem needs full stack custom software is just part of how to solve the business problem. Speak to their problem and show how you will solve it.